# Javascript select and use an object using another variable's value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've got several tables in mongodb with a similar name:

```
var fruit_prices = db.collection('fruit_prices');
var vegetables_prices = db.collection('vegetables_prices');
var tuber_prices = db.collection('tuber_prices');
```

The following code has to work for the three tables. To do so, I need transform the food_type variable's value into one of the three vars defined before so that later i can call a find method in any of the tables:

```
// food_type can be fruit, vegetables or tuber
var table = food_type+'_prices';
// instead of [table] i should use another expression that works..this is not working
[table].find({},{'_id': false}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
//whatever here
});
```

How can this be done?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all three of them on an object:

```
var prices = {
    fruit: db.collection('fruit_prices'),
    vegetables: db.collection('vegetables_prices'),
    tuber: db.collection('tuber_prices')
};
```

Then when you need to use one:

```
var food = 'fruit';
prices[food].find({},{'_id': false}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    //whatever here
});
```